# Are there any 802.11ac adapters working in Ubuntu?

Tags: wireless, drivers, 12.10, peripherals

Has anyone got an 802.11ac adapter working in Linux/Ubuntu? PCI or USB. Looks like the a6200 might be having [issues](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1066308/). And according to [wikidev](http://www.wikidevi.com/wiki/List_of_802.11ac_Hardware), it's the only released piece of client hardware for 802.11ac.

Comment: Not YET... at least not natively in the kernel. There is a confirmed case of an ASUS PCE-AC66 working with ndiswrapper (see http://askubuntu.com/questions/251163/is-there-a-way-to-get-broadcom-802-11ac-wifi-43b1-working-on-ubuntu-12-10) with *unsecured* networks. You can see an automatically updated list of hardware at wikidev here: http://wikidevi.com/wiki/List_of_802.11ac_Hardware#Automatically_updated_tables

Comment: The `ac` wireless standard is so new that not much is actually built for it yet.  In time technology will catch up but at this time I don't think there's any hardware that works with it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a shopping advice question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I saw your post two weeks ago. I did some research and found one online.

I can confirm that edimax EW-7822UAC provide Linux driver. I successfully compiled its driver and connected it in Fedora 19. The download speed can reach average 15MB/s and peak 20MB/s by using perf.

This is the output of `iwconfig` and `lsusb`:

```
$ iwconfig
enp6s0u2  IEEE 802.11AC  ESSID:"Orz-5Ghz"  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.2 GHz  Access Point: 74:D0:2B:41:EC:FC   
      Bit Rate:867 Mb/s   Sensitivity:0/0  
      Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:off
      Link Quality=100/100  Signal level=94/100  Noise level=0/100
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

$ lsusb
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 7392:a822 Edimax Technology Co., Ltd
```

Comment: Wow, awesome :) That one went under the radar for sure. Not great speed though, but that seems to be a complaint from a few windows users as well ( http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833315123 )

Comment: Can confirm it's working great under Ubuntu 13.04. 
- Download driver from http://www.edimax.com/en/support_detail.php?pd_id=479&pl1_id=28&pl2_id=138 
- run make && sudo make install from extracted folder
- sudo modprobe 8812au 
- add 8812au to /etc/modules

Comment: In kernel 3.10.x above, because of changing proc entry registration function, current driver can't succeed compiling . The modification is quite boring. I'd wait for Realtek release a patch. But I'm not sure the time line

Comment: It's working with this updated driver: https://github.com/abperiasamy/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux clone the repo or download zip and follow the same procedure as the previous edimax-provided driver

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm that the Intel 7260 Mini-PCIe WiFi adapter works on Mint 15 (based on Ubuntu 13.04) with the kernel backport driver kit from kernel 3.11.6. The same card should also work on 13.10, as from my understanding it's using a 3.11-based kernel. You might have to drop in the latest firmware, but I have it up and working on my ThinkPad X220 (with a modded BIOS):

```
[  175.842808] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7260, REV=0x144
```

See [the kernel iwlwifi driver page](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/iwlwifi) for more info, links to firmware and the backported driver source page. I haven't yet tested it with a .11ac base station, but I hope to soon.