# Is there a way to get Broadcom 802.11ac WiFi (43b1) working on Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: networking, broadcom, asus, windows-8

I have a dual boot of Windows 8 / Ubuntu 12.10 on an ASUS G75VX with Broadcom 802.11ac Network adapter device 43b1. It seems that there exists no drivers for this adapter. I have done all of the instructions in the following post:

[No Wireless connectivity after installing Ubuntu 12.10 on Windows 8](https://askubuntu.com/questions/211370/no-wireless-connectivity-after-installing-ubuntu-12-10-on-windows-8)

Some info:

```
sudo iwconfig
eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

lspci -nn | grep 0280
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation Device [14e4:43b1] (rev 03)
```

After doing the instructions of the link above, I realized I didn't have the option to install `bcmwl-sta-source` from synaptic. Furthermore, from the list of devices that the  `bcmwl-kernel-source` supports, it doesn't include this specific model. Is it not supported yet?

Please let me know if anyone has gotten around to this issue. It will bug me alot if I just bought a new laptop and can't use the super fast wireless connection it provides :(

P.S in Windows 8 it works fine.

Comment: Good question. But unfortunately, a Google search on these device IDs give me **nothing** except this question. As if you're the only one with this device! I think this should be filed as a bug report. Hardware in Ubuntu should *just work*. And if it doesn't - support for it should be added by developers. [How do I report a bug?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)

Comment: You might try ndiswrapper. Over on the Windows partition, are there .inf files for the device? Any for Windows XP? Do you have a driver disk from which we can extract the XP inf and sys files? Of course, you could buy a cheap USB wireless device and wait.

Comment: any leads? im having the same problem aswell.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Linux wireless LAN support](http://linux-wless.passys.nl/query_chipset.php?chipset=Broadcom) there is no support yet.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, ndiswrapper can actually get this device to work. Download the Windows XP driver for the ASUS PCE-AC66 from here: http://www.asus.com/Networking/PCEAC66/#support_Download_17 and install it with ndiswrapper.

Disclaimer: I have only used it with Ubuntu 13.04 and ndiswrapper 1.58 and only for a few hours...
Disclaimer2: It seems I can only get it to work with unsecured networks, but this might be a problem with wpa_supplicant...

Answer (score 0):

Is is possible to fix using an older version of the driver, see bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1173761

But actually I would rather recommend to replace the network module with another one that has a better driver status. I ended up replacing it with an "Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260" module which works fine out of the box. Be sure that your BIOS does not contain a whitelist for allowed network modules in this case.