# Drivers for Wireless card Asus PCE-AC66?

Tags: wireless, networking

Where can I get an Ubuntu driver for this card? is there any? otherwise can I install a generic Wireless driver even if it works sub-optimally but at least will work.

UPDATE:

As per the comments and running:

```
$ lspci -nn -d 14e4:
82:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation Device [14e4:43a0] (rev 02)
```

But note that my board Z9PE-D8 WS board comes with an integrated network card (actually two I believe) but I need the Wireless.

Comment: Take a look at this [Post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/251163/is-there-a-way-to-get-broadcom-802-11ac-wifi-43b1-working-on-ubuntu-12-10), see if it helps.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the device ID for your card from this terminal command: lspci -nn -d 14e4:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an Arch Linux question that deals with your exact same device 14e4:43a0. https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/wireless-bcm43142-dkms/ The proposed solution is the latest version of bcmwl-kernel-source, in that case 6.30.223.30-1. The result reported later was: "THANK YOU!!! It works as expected."

In Ubuntu 13.04, there is a proposed version of bcmwl-kernel-source 6.30.223.30+bdcom-0ubuntu3. If you are running 13.04, open Software and Updates and select Prereleased Updates under the Updates tab. With a temporary ethernet connection, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Check the version that was installed:

```
sudo dpkg -s bcmwl-kernel-source
```

It should say: Version: 6.30.223.30+bdcom-0ubuntu3

Now load the driver:

```
sudo modprobe wl
```

Is it working now? So that you don't get a lot of unstable software, go back and uncheck Prereleased Updates and re-run:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: So does this work? I have the router but not the card, and I run Mint.

Comment: @RonaldoNascimento  I doubt it. Please start a new question and tell us  your card details from lspci -nn | grep 0280